# highlight python docstrings as comments with emacs

Tags: python, emacs, documentation, comments, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to customise emacs such that python docstrings are highlighted the same way as comments are? Here is an example of a python docstring

```
def python_function(argument):
    """
    doc string here

    may be multiline
    """
    return some_func(argument)
```

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/5130088/3001761 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/27317396/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, didn't see them. thanks for pointing me to them! Unfortunately, they don't come with the answer (the accepted answers do not answer the question satisfactorily)

Comment: Then could you edit this one to be more specific about how it differs and what from the existing answers falls short?

Comment: There are two major modes for python in common usage, `python-mode.el` from Python devs, and `python.el` which comes with Emacs.  I quickly looked through `python.el` and didn't see anything to highlight docstrings differently than strings.  The other answers imply that `python-mode.el` does do this.  So you either need to install `python-mode.el` or add the functionality to `python.el`.  FWIW, I used `python-mode.el` years ago and switched to `python.el`, and I feel like it was a good move, but there have been enormous changes in both libraries since then.

Comment: @jpkotta I don't have root access to the system, so how can I *install* either of these? Where does it go (if I do have root access)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe These 'answers' don't answer the question. (full stop). I want a solution, not a hint that requires in-depth knowledge of the inner workings of emacs.

Comment: @Walter perhaps you'd like someone to pop round and set up your machine for you?

Comment: @Walter You don't need root access, it can be installed in `~/.emacs.d`.  You can set up the emacs package manager (use google, there are many, many guides) and use it to install `python-mode` (available in the melpa repo).  If you're going to use emacs, you want to figure out the package system.  It's not hard and will pay dividends many times over.

Answer (score 1):

With python-mode.el, customize `font-lock-doc-face` accordingly.
This needs also `py-use-font-lock-doc-face-p` set to `t`.

Besides all faces are customizable. 
M-x `customize-face` RET `font-lock-string-face` RET and set it to the value wanted. However this would affect all modes.

Comment: If it was that easy, I wouldn't have asked. If I change the `font-lock-string-face`, *all* strings are affected, but I want only to change the docstrings.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not a emacs wizard and no nothing about `python-mode.el`. Where, what, how?

Comment: @Walter Easiest probably to install via melpa.

Answer (score 0):

As of Emacs 25.1, Emacs' bulit-in `python.el` displays docstrings with `font-lock-doc-face`.